# Google Analytics + Kickstarter

Tags: google-analytics

need a little help.

We have a website where both non-www and www.domain.com forward to an ongoing Kickstarter campaign.  Kickstarter has its own reporting tools, which shows the domains (and subdomains) where the backers are coming from.  Unfortunately it's not detailed enough - for example it does not show whether a Facebook visitor is coming from an ad or just clicked on a link someone shared.

We have Google Analytics on domain.com and www.domain.com so when a visitor comes through that way, we can track them.

What I want to achieve is to connect info I get from Google Analytics to Kickstarter stats and I thought I'd use subdomains for that.

For example, if we are running a Facebook ad campaign, I'd like it to land on fb.domain.com and then redirect to Kickstarter and hope that it will show fb.domain.com as the source, when the visitor pledges.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `But then we` was there more of this?

Comment: Most of the time, for security, companies don't allow javascript to run in their apps/sites. Since analytics use Javascript you're probably out of luck unless you can bend a project field to allow it. Kickstarter has some sort of unofficial API though, so maybe if you're lucky, it could mitigate/inject analytics (unlikely).

Comment: DHaupin, thank you for responding. I am not trying to run anything on their website. They already recognize subdomains in their analytics, I just want to redirect our tragic in a way so that I can tell how it got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a question and found a solution M2Z ;)

It is right way to create the subdomain for particular source e.g fb.domain.com for FB incoming traffic. You can add some UTMs for campaign/ad tagging, probably You know that.

Remember to delay a redirection (something like "Please wait..." + 100ms waiting time), to be sure that analytics js was triggered

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Kickstarter just introduced today a Google Analytics integration. Accordingly, you don't need to redirect your page (with a delay)...just plug in your Google Analytics ID.